# Getting around the lack of IsNumeric() function in SQL CE?

Tags: sql-server-ce

SQL Server CE (3.5) doesn't appear to support the `IsNumeric` function.  What are some alternatives to achieve the same functionality?  Specifically, how would you test whether a `CAST` from a string to a `DECIMAL` datatype will succeed in SQLCE without `IsNumeric`?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to explicitly add an `ISNUMERIC` column to the table, and set the value (in your code, using your own method or a built-in .NET method) whenever the row is added or updated.

Another possibility is to [use a query like this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30160611/how-to-check-if-value-is-not-numeric.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: Typically what `IsNumeric`, `IsDate` and their ilk are used for is for making sure a `CAST` will succeed, and providing a reasonable default if it doesn't.  You'd need to support initial negative signs and decimals and potentially the 'e' notation, and with all those considerations the statement becomes huge.  Sure, a big-fat-brute-force `case` statement would get the job done, but I'm hoping there's something more, uh, reasonable already built in.